# How do I add a unique auto generated number on Google Sheets that stays unique even if you add and remove rows?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like to create a cell in a Google sheet containing a unique auto incremented number of the form XYZn where n is the auto incremented number. This number must stay unique so using the row() function is not an option.

I tried the following originally:

="XYZ" & row()

But as I explained before, this means that adding or removing rows before this row will cause the number to change. I want this number to stay fixed.

Perhaps a random number could be used but it may generate a number that is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Select a cell and enter:

```
="XYZ" & TEXT(NOW(),"yyyymmddhhmmss")
```

Then copy the cell and pastespecial value back onto itself.

The value will be unique and stay unique even if rows are added/removed.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. So basically we are using the time to make it unique. The difference here is the Paste Special or Ctrl Shift V.

I have modified it slightly as follows:
="V-" & TEXT(NOW(),"yy-mdhm-s")

Comment: @VinceDeMello  Good idea.